# How can I know exactly which songs I have purchased from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, accounts

The purchase history of iTunes and the email receipts don't show me exactly which version (i.e. album and song number) of a song I have previously purchased.

How can I view this information?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to navigate to iTunes new interface for albums (not search results) (e.g. by clicking the album's name). Instead of seeing the song price, you will see the word "Purchased".

To get to the song's album, you can either search for the artist and try the 1-3 likely albums the song might be located in until you find the "purchased" text, or you could click the "Write a Review" link for the song in your email receipt. Note that when you click the "Write a Review" link, you will be taken to iTunes old interface for albums. You must click the album name at the top to get to the new interface, which shows the "Purchased" text.

Another thing to note is that I noticed that if a song you purchased belongs to an album with only one song (i.e. it's the only song in the album), the "Purchased" text won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Create a smart playlist and use "kind contains protected" as the first rule and "kind contains purchased" as a second rule.

Comment: Sorry I should have explicitly mentioned that I don't have the music files anymore.

Comment: then you're out of luck, you cannot redownload them again for free (like you do with apps). You will need to purchase them again.

Comment: @VictorJalencas this is no longer true, by accessing iTunes on a device you can see all iTunes that have been downloaded, you can also see which files are not on this device, from this menu you can choose download all

Comment: of course, it was true at the time of posting

Answer (score 0):

if you go to iTunes on your device and you can navigate to the purchased section, this will then list all the songs you have purchased on iTunes, you will also be able to download the songs to your device if you haven't got them on there already.